# How to connect google drive and get list folders and arrange as a tree using php?

Tags: php, laravel

How to connect google drive and get list folders and arrange as a tree using php?

[image]

Comment: Did you check : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/#resource-types

Comment: What have you even tried?

Comment: Yes. I have tried this one. I have get all files. But How can I seperate folders and files return from this function $service->files->listFiles($optParams).???

Comment: How can I get "mimeType" because this list only file include folder. I want seperate folders and files.???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTP api provided by Google to retrieve the results [Google Cloud API PHP Wrapper](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

Comment: Yes I have try this want. I focus on how to seperate file and folder because,$service->files->listFiles($optParams) only return files.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\newlogin\quickstart.php on line 140. well I got this error and I can't find any help. Anyone can help me??